# How to display price of product based on product unit in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
[
  {
    "categoryId": 0,
    "discountPrice": 100,
    "productDescription": "Abc",
    "productId": "2N04L1O4L4",
    "productImage": "image1.jpg",
    "productName": "Abc",
    "productPrice": 200,
    "productUnit": "1kg",
    "quantity": 0
  },
  {
    "categoryId": 0,
    "discountPrice": 300,
    "productDescription": "abc",
    "productId": "2N04L1O4L4",
    "productImage": "http://image1.jpg",
    "productName": "Abc",
    "productPrice": 400,
    "productUnit": "2kg",
    "quantity": 0
  },
  {
    "categoryId": 0,
    "discountPrice": 500,
    "productDescription": "good",
    "productId": "A0091JNG4O",
    "productImage": "image2.jpg",
    "productName": "Xyz",
    "productPrice": 500,
    "productUnit": "1kg",
    "quantity": 0
  },
  {
    "categoryId": 0,
    "discountPrice": 250,
    "productDescription": "Demo",
    "productId": "QQ769GPQJ2",
    "productImage": "image33.jpg",
    "productName": "Toor dal",
    "productPrice": 250,
    "productUnit": "1kg",
    "quantity": 0
  }
]
```

Hi, i am working on eCommerce application. This is my json.
Here one product having multiple prices(200,300...etc) based on units(KG,2KG..etc). I want to display as one product but when i select different product unit, how to get price of that product.
How to achive this in Angularjs.

Comment: What currently have you tried.

Comment: I created two arrays one for image,name,description, other for price,discountprice,productunits. In both arrays productid is key. But i did not achive what i want.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to have more information and a JSFiddle for us to assist..

You might reconsider the structure of your data. A product could have options.

Here's a JSFiddle which i hope answers your question:

http://jsfiddle.net/ltfleming/3sfrxex5/3/

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {


  $scope.product = {
    name: 'Flour',
    options: [{
      "categoryId": 0,
      "discountPrice": 100,
      "productDescription": "Abc",
      "productId": "2N04L1O4L4",
      "productImage": "image1.jpg",
      "productName": "Abc",
      "productPrice": 200,
      "productUnit": "1kg",
      "quantity": 0
    }, {
      "categoryId": 0,
      "discountPrice": 300,
      "productDescription": "abc",
      "productId": "2N04L1O4L4",
      "productImage": "http://image1.jpg",
      "productName": "Abc",
      "productPrice": 400,
      "productUnit": "2kg",
      "quantity": 0
    }, {
      "categoryId": 0,
      "discountPrice": 500,
      "productDescription": "good",
      "productId": "A0091JNG4O",
      "productImage": "image2.jpg",
      "productName": "Xyz",
      "productPrice": 500,
      "productUnit": "1kg",
      "quantity": 0
    }, {
      "categoryId": 0,
      "discountPrice": 250,
      "productDescription": "Demo",
      "productId": "QQ769GPQJ2",
      "productImage": "image33.jpg",
      "productName": "Toor dal",
      "productPrice": 250,
      "productUnit": "1kg",
      "quantity": 0
    }]
  };

}
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <h1>
    {{product.name}}
  </h1>

  <select ng-model="selectedOption" ng-options="option.productName for option in product.options">
    <option value="">-- choose option --</option>
  </select>

  <div ng-if='selectedOption'>
    <p>
      <label for="">Product ID:</label>{{selectedOption.productId}}</p>
    <p>
      <label for="">Description:</label>{{selectedOption.productDescription}}</p>
    <p>
      <label for="">Price:</label>{{selectedOption.productPrice}}</p>
  </div>
  <img ng-src="{{selectedOption.productImage}}" alt="image">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response Liam Fleming. I will try.

Comment: I used ng-repeat instead of ng-options,but it is not working

Comment: Can you add a JSFiddle please.